# Scalatags, cannot return div() from other class

Tags: scala, scalatags

I'd like to split different html-parts into own classes and now I don't understand one thing regarding this code(-snippet):

```
val z = for(a <- 0 to 5) yield div(s"$a")
body(h1("Testing stuff"), z)
```

works just fine.

So does:

```
body(h1("Testing stuff"), test)
private def test = for(a <- 0 to 5) yield div(s"$a")
```

What does **not** work is this:

```
class Test[Builder, Output <: FragT, FragT](val bundle: scalatags.generic.Bundle[Builder, Output, FragT])
{
    import bundle.all._

    def render = for(a <- 0 to 5) yield div(s"$a")
}
```

---

```
val test = new Test(scalatags.Text)
body(h1("Testing stuff"), test.render)
```

This wont compile. It says (once the `h1()` is removed)

{quote}
Type mismatch, expected: Modifier[Builder], actual: IndexedSeq[test.bundle.all.Div.Self]
{quote}

And I simply do not understand why. Is there some implicit magic going on? Can one enlighten me and show me how it's done?

**edit:**

To further clarify the difference between mine and @Owen 's code:

In the other class (where I initialize a new `Test`) I did import `bundle.all.all_` as well (derived from same base), but not import `scalatags.Text.all._`. So in the second package there seem to be some implicits that take care of the conversion. (Although I haven't found them yet.)

I also find it quite funny that this is not the same as `import bundle.all._` when I am passing `scalatags.Text` as bundle after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code compiles fine for me. Here's the full code I compiled:

```
object TagTest1 {
  class Test[Builder, Output <: FragT, FragT](val bundle: scalatags.generic.Bundle[Builder, Output, FragT]) {
    import bundle.all._

    def render = for(a <- 0 to 5) yield div(s"$a")
  }

  {
    import scalatags.Text.all._

    val test = new Test(scalatags.Text)
    body(h1("Testing stuff"), test.render)
  }
}
```

---

**edit**: I just encountered this error again today, googled it, and found this question. :)

In case it helps anyone, I have since learned the following things:

#### Debugging implicits

Put the following in your `build.sbt`:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-Xprint:typer"
)
```

(`-Yprint:typer` seems to have been removed).

#### This particular implicit

Based on `-Xprint:typer`, I determined the implicit needed to use a `Seq` of elements in another element is `scalatags.Text.all.SeqFrag`.

Comment: And here is the difference: In the other class I did `import bundle.all.all_` as well (derived from same base), but *not* `import scalatags.Text.all._`. So in the second package there seem to be some implicits that take care of the conversion. Although I haven't found them yet. I find that especially funny since `bundle.all._` should be the same as `scalatags.Text.all._` as I'm passing `scalatags.Text` as `bundle` :/ Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Sorona If you need to find a particular implicit, `-Yprint:typer` is a good way.